# The remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized

Tags: development, csom, sharepoint-server

I have install a fresh version of SharePoint 2019 which is on domain A,then i added a second computer to A which will be hosting websites on IIS.

I have created a console application just for testing connection to SharePoint on the second computer using the code below and am getting unauthorized access.Is there anything wrong with the code below?. Note the credentials are correct.

```
        System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(@"DoaminNAme\administrator","Password");

        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://10.1.1.1/sharepoint2019/sites/test/"))
        {
            clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

            clientContext.Credentials = cred;

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult<System.IO.Stream> stream = null;

            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);

            keywordQuery.QueryText = "SharePoint";

            keywordQuery.EnablePhonetic = true;

            keywordQuery.EnableOrderingHitHighlightedProperty = true;
            //keywordQuery.SummaryLength = 500;


            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);

            ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: The code looks fine. The url seems a bit strange and the `NetworkCredential`s, too. I have never used `domain\\user` when using `NetworkCredential`. I always use `new NetworkCredential ("user", "password", "domain");`

Comment: @Nils i changed the NetworkCredentials as per your guideline but the error persist. Yes the URL is strange, i was not sure what to use,can you give me an example please

Comment: You'll need the same url that is used when accessing SharePoint using a browser. Typically it should look somthing like `https://sharepoint.server/sites/sitename`

Comment: @Nils If i used this links https://sharepoint2019/sites/sitename i get the error cannot resolve the name sharepoint2019

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have the correct URL for your SharePoint/Location.

I'd suggest using a simple browser (Chrome, FF, IE, whatever). If you can not access your SharePoint using the browser, the code will probably never work.

Comment: Ya the url was incorrect in my case. The servername was incorrect in my case